# Tracking events in twitter lists (nodejs / meteor)

Tags: node.js, list, twitter, meteor, stream

Is there an easy way to track tweets in twitter lists in "real-time"? Here is an example list:  https://twitter.com/StartupDorf/lists/startups-im-startupdorf

I thought about using [twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit), and first retrieve a list of all members and then track these users.
Here is my current approach which works in two steps:

```
// first, fetch a list of all list members
T.get('lists/members', {id: 1282843634, list_id: 95809626, count: 5000}, function (err, data, response) {
    if (err) {
        //
    } else {
        data.users.forEach(function (user) {
            follow.push(user.id)
        });
    }
});

// I haven't seen a .done() method, so I'm just waiting 3 seconds to start with the stream.
Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(follow, follow.length);
    var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', {follow: follow});

    stream.on('tweet', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }))
}, 3000);
```

So, how can I auto-update my Stream event if a new member was added to the list?

Comment: Have you tried defining a reactive data source on your T.get() function ? I think defining it as a dependency with Tracker and then replacing your setTimeout by a Tracker.autorun function.